# Navigate through ASP.Net AjaxControllToolKit Tabs using button click

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, asp.net-ajax, tabcontainer

I am using ASP.NET AjaxControllToolKit Tab Container  , I have 9 tabs in it i want to switch to next tabs on asp:button click.
I have a screen shot of my tabs .
[image: This is my sample Asp.Net ajax tab container]

I try this C# code but it is not working .

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            TabContainer1.ActiveTab = TabContainer1.Tabs[2];

        }
```

Please give me the right solution for navigation between tabs on button clicks.

Comment: Can you post all of your code-behind, including `Page_Load`?

Comment: Yes i done all my code in code behind and use update panel for each tab to avoid full page post back , when i click on the next button on each tab the data is uploaded in database and i want the tab should be changed after data uploaded.

Comment: Okay, have you debugged to see if the `TabContainer1.Tabs` collection has any items in it? I am wondering if the collection is somehow getting cleared, which is why I asked you to post all of your code-behind. Without that, I am just guessing at what might be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code Work fine if you have **enable AutoPostBack** of Tab Container.

```
TabContainer1.ActiveTab = TabContainer1.Tabs[1];
```